# C++ Client/Socket issue

Tags: c++, sockets

I've just started to learn some C++ and wanted to make a simple client/server connection using sockets. I've been following this tutorial more or less: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WaLQ7s1X6wo

Anyway, here's the client and server code.

```
// Client.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#define SCK_VERSION2 0x0202;

#include <sdkddkver.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WSAData WinSockData;
    WORD DLLVERSION = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

    if (long checkWSA = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION, &WinSockData) == 0){
        std::cout << "\nWinSock started up jolly and good.";
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "\nWinsock failed for reason such as : " << checkWSA;
    }
    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(IN_ADDR)); //ignore this

    SOCKADDR_IN ADDRESS;
    InetPton(AF_INET, (PCTSTR)"127.0.0.1", &ADDRESS.sin_addr);
    ADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ADDRESS.sin_port = htons(444);

    std::cout << "\nAttempting to connect";

    SOCKET sock;
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);



    if (int connectTry = connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS, sizeof(ADDRESS)) == 0){
        std::cout << " Connection successful? : " << connectTry;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << " Connection unsuccessful? : " << connectTry;
    }

    char MESSAGE[200];

    if (recv(sock, MESSAGE, sizeof(MESSAGE), NULL)){
        std::string str(MESSAGE);
        std::cout << "\nReceived from server: " << str;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "\nNope.";
    }

    std::cout << "\nEnd";
    std::cin >> buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

Server

```
    #define SCK_VERSION2 0x0202;

    #include <sdkddkver.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <WS2tcpip.h>

    #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        WSAData WinSockData;
        WORD DLLVERSION = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

        //Starts winsock dll
        if (long checkWSA = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION, &WinSockData) == 0){
            std::cout << "\nWinSock started up jolly and good.";
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "\nWinsock failed for reason such as : " << checkWSA;
        }

        //Make socket structure
        char* buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(IN_ADDR)); //ignore this

        SOCKADDR_IN ADDRESS;
        int AddressSize = sizeof(ADDRESS);
        InetPton(AF_INET, (PCTSTR)"127.0.0.1", &ADDRESS.sin_addr);
        ADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
        ADDRESS.sin_port = htons(444);

        SOCKET 

sock_CONNECTION = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

    SOCKET sock_LISTEN = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind(sock_LISTEN, (SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS, sizeof(ADDRESS));
    listen(sock_LISTEN, SOMAXCONN);

    std::cout << "\nWaiting for connection...";

    if (sock_CONNECTION = accept(sock_LISTEN, (SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS, &AddressSize)){
        std::cout << "\nConnected to: " << ADDRESS.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr;
        std::cout << "\n\n" << WSAGetLastError();
        send(sock_CONNECTION, "Welcome to the Wonderland!", 46, NULL);
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "\nNope";
    }

    std::cout << "\nEnd";
    std::cin >> buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

[image: Output]

I'm guessing the problem child here is this line:

```
ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = InetPton(AF_INET, (PCTSTR)"127.0.0.1", &ADDRESS.sin_addr);
```

I couldn't use inet_addr because the compiler was telling me to use InetPton() or else #define _WINDOWS_IGNORE or something like that in order to ignore the error. Needless to say, I couldn't get it to define properly and ignore the error so I went with InetPton().

Anyone know what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Not usually a good idea putting images into a question

Comment: @EdHeal Not unless it illustrates the problem more clearly.

Comment: In this case is does not - and only in a few cases it does

Comment: well, the picture did help me see the code path both processes took... although you could certainly argue the text of that could have been copied into the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks correct more or less... note that your server-side never sends anything to the accepted connection in handle `sock_CONNECTION` and also you end up leaking the socket you created into that variable before the `accept`.  In your client, your receive doesn't zero-terminate the message... the length is returned from the `recv` call, which should be zero since you never sent it anything.  Hence, you're just printing an uninitialized array.

**edit 1**: successful `connect` returns zero so your logic is backwards there, so it looks like it connected OK but it did not, which leads to:

**edit 2**: your call to `InetPton` is overwriting the address in the return which is just `1` on success... so it's trying to connect to the wrong place.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I've edited the code in the OP with the fixed to the errors you've pointed out. Except I'm not sure what you mean that I leak the socket that I've created before the accept. The client now actually awaits to connect but never connects, because the server throws an error with WSAGETLASTERROR. In MSDN it says that the error is Some invalid argument was supplied (for example, specifying an invalid level to the setsockopt function). In some instances, it also refers to the current state of the socket—for instance, calling accept on a socket that is not listening.

Comment: I suspect your last issue is your default character set is wide-chars, and that your cast in `InetPton` to a `(PCTSTR)` is invalid.  I suspect that if you simply made it `InetPton( AF_INET, L"127.0.0.1", &ADDRESS.sin_addr );` (NOTE: `L` in front of the string) that all would be good in Wonderland!

Comment: Oh yeah, I've figured out that Pton was returning 0 instead of 1 and was looking at MSDN and it said " InetPton function returns a value of 0 if the pAddrBuf parameter points to a string that is not a valid IPv4 dotted-decimal string" but that tripped me up a bit because pAddrBuf is the pointer to the buffer. Thanks, everything works now, although all of the string types are confusing @.@